# at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {errno: -54, code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'}

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am doing some fetches to the API and database operation in the script. However, I have no idea which line of code led to this error, and I don't know what this error is about, how can I extract more information about it?

```
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11323
            fetchParams.controller.controller.error(new TypeError("terminated", {
                                                    ^

TypeError: terminated
    at Fetch.onAborted (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11323:53)
    at Fetch.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Fetch.terminate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10578:14)
    at Object.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11418:36)
    at Request.onError (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8210:31)
    at errorRequest (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10264:17)
    at TLSSocket.onSocketClose (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:9710:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at node:net:322:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7) {
  [cause]: Error: read ECONNRESET
      at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
    errno: -54,
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read'
  }
}
```